# Windows - Get the URLs passed by the computer?

Tags: windows, http, url, windows-installer, http-post

In Windows how to retrieve the URLs passed by the computer? I mean any URLs browsed by the web browsers. The reason is I have an installer which sends an HTTP POST via an URL to the web server. However I do not have the source code of the installer. How to get the URL passed by this installer?

Comment: Wireshark. {filler for minimum comment length}

Comment: [theB](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5240004/theb), does the Wireshark show the HTTP URLs?

Comment: Yes. You can even trace an entire http connection. Also, to reply to comments, just use the @ sign and their name without any spaces. Like: `@CodenameK` or `@theB`

Comment: @theB, can you show examples of how Wireshark can be used to get the URLs please?